# merge different dataframes and add other columns from base dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge different dataframes.

Assume these two melted `dataframes`.

`melted_dfs[0]`=

```
        Date      Code       delta_7
0   2014-04-01     GWA        0.08
1   2014-04-02     TVV       -0.98
```

`melted_dfs[1] =`

```
       Date       Code       delta_14
0   2014-04-01     GWA         nan
1   2014-04-02     XRP       -1.02
```

I am looking to merge both the above dataframes along with `volume`& `GR` columns from my base `dataframe`.

`base_df =`

```
     Date         Code      Volume       GR
0   2014-04-01     XRP    74,776.48    482.76
1   2014-04-02     TRR   114,052.96    460.19
```

I tried to use Python's built in `reduce` function by converting all dataframes into a list but it throws a error

```
abt = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y,on=['Date', 'Code']), feature_dfs)
# feature_dfs is a list which contains all the above dfs.
```

`ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work , as it stated some of df's date is not datetime format

```
feature_dfs=[x.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(x['Date'])) for x in feature_dfs]

abt = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y,on=['Date', 'Code']), feature_dfs)
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks Wen.

Answer (score 1):

One of your dataframes in `feature_dfs` probably has a non-datetime dtype.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the datatypes and index of the DataFrames:

```
for i, df in enumerate(feature_dfs):
    print 'DataFrame index: {}'.format(str(i))
    print df.info()
    print '-'*72
```

I would assume that one of the DataFrames is going to show a line like:

```
Date    X non-null object
```

Indicating that you don't have a datetime datatype for Date.  That DataFrame is the culprit and you will have the index from the print above.

Comment: One of the dfs didn't had a `datetime dtype`. Thanks.